# Convert nested array of objects to specific group of objects of the data in JavaScript or TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I am having a double nested array of objects and I would like to change to a specific array of groups to support my table structure.

Below are my objects and the result I am expecting.

```js
let newData = {
  data: {
    summary: [
      {
        code: "12",
        data: [
          {
            group: "Trade",
            currency: "CAD", //group1
            amount: "$3,443.00",
            total: 1
          },
          {
            group: "Trade",
            currency: "USD", //group2
            amount: "$0.00",
            total: 0
          },
          {
            group: "Commission",
            currency: "CAD", //group3
            amount: "$0.00",
            total: 0
          },
          {
            group: "Commission",
            currency: "USD", //group4
            amount: "$0.00",
            total: 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        code: "34",
        data: [
          {
            group: "Trade",
            currency: "CAD", //group1
            amount: "$343.00",
            total: 21
          },
          {
            group: "Trade",
            currency: "USD", //group2
            amount: "$40.00",
            total: 40
          },
          {
            group: "Commission",
            currency: "CAD", //group3
            amount: "$30.00",
            total: 30
          },
          {
            group: "Commission",
            currency: "USD", //group4
            amount: "$20.00",
            total: 20
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};



let result = [
{
    code: "12",
    TradeCAD:
    {
            group: "Trade",
            currency: "CAD", //group1
            amount: "$3,443.00",
            total: 1
          },
     TradeUSD:     
           {
            group: "Trade",
            currency: "USD", //group2
            amount: "$0.00",
            total: 0
          },
     CommissionCAD:     {
            group: "Commission",
            currency: "CAD", //group3
            amount: "$0.00",
            total: 0
          },
     CommissionUSD:     {
            group: "Commission",
            currency: "USD", //group4
            amount: "$0.00",
            total: 0
          }

       
  },
  {
    code: "34",
    TradeCAD:
    {
            group: "Trade",
            currency: "CAD", //group1
            amount: "$343.00",
            total: 21
          },
     TradeUSD:     
           {
            group: "Trade",
            currency: "USD", //group2
            amount: "$40.00",
            total: 40
          },
     CommissionCAD:     {
            group: "Commission",
            currency: "CAD", //group3
            amount: "$30.00",
            total: 30
          },
     CommissionUSD:     {
            group: "Commission",
            currency: "USD", //group4
            amount: "$20.00",
            total: 20
          }

       
  },
];
```

How I can iterate and change the whole object and If I do have a lot of data which is the best approach to follow to support fewer iterations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, and see if work. you can condense the code into one function if you want to.

```js
const result = newData.data.summary.map(item => {
  const res = {
    code: item.code,
  }
  item.data.forEach(d => {
    res[`${d.group}${d.currency}`] = d;
    d.amount = d.amount || "$0.00"; // default value for amount
    d.total = d.total || 0; // default value for total
  })
  return res;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: It's working perfect thanks. Just a question.. how we can handle null check if the object is missing or any property is not there?

Comment: can you provide an example? :-)

Comment: if this object is missing in code: "34", {
            group: "Trade",
            currency: "CAD", //group1
            amount: "$343.00",
            total: 21
          },

Comment: or  code: "34", missing group: "Trade" value

Comment: How we can check this kind of scenario?

Comment: how do you want to handle cases like this? do you want to discard the entry or set some default values to the missing values?

Comment: yes I would like to default values as my group,currency,amount,total parameter is fixed.. I would like to default to 0 if something is missing or not exist.

Comment: i have updated my answer, please cross check